# Formik Initial Values don't populate from api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, formik

I'm fetching data from my backend based on an id in the params. The data is fetched fine from looking at the console log including different values, such as product.title.

I want to be able to edit my product using formik but for some reason, the initial values won't populate in the input field even tho everything is set perfectly.

When i console log formik.initialvalues, it shows that product.title is undefined.

Here is my useEffect code to fetch data:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProductById = async () => {
          try {
            const response  = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${prodId}`)
            setProduct(response.data)
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
          }
        }
        fetchProductById();
      },[prodId]);
```

Here is my formik initial values (I'm using product.title as an example):

```
    const editProductFormik = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
        title: product.title,
        description: '',
        price: '',
        images: images,
        coverImage: coverImage,
        location: '',
        age: '',
        condition: '',
        Category: '',
        SubCategory : '',
        seller : seller,
      },
```

Here is my input for Product Title :

```
                <Box>
                <Input mr={2} width="250px" type="title" value={editProductFormik.values.title} onChange={editProductFormik.handleChange("title")} marginBottom="10px" />
                {editProductFormik.touched.title && editProductFormik.errors.title ? (
                    <Text mt={2} color="red" fontWeight="bold">{editProductFormik.errors.title}</Text>
                  ) : null}
                </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. In order for initialValues in Formik to work with backend data, the values must be passed as props to the child component that holds the formik, otherwise the values will be undefined.

Here is my parent component :

```
const ParentProduct = () => {


  const {prodId} = useParams();

const [product, setProduct] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProductById = async () => {
    try {
      const response  = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3005/product/${prodId}`)
      setProduct(response.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
  fetchProductById();
},[prodId]);

  return (
    <EditProduct product={product} />
  )
}

export default ParentProduct
```

Here is my child component that holds formik :

```
const EditProduct = ({product}) => {
const editProductFormik = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
        title: product.title,
        description: '',
        price: '',
        images: images,
        coverImage: coverImage,
        location: '',
        age: product.age,
        condition: '',
        Category: '',
        SubCategory : '',
        seller : seller,
      },
          <Box>
                <Input mr={2} width="250px" type="title" color="black" value={editProductFormik.values.title} onChange={editProductFormik.handleChange("title")} marginBottom="10px" />
                {editProductFormik.touched.title && editProductFormik.errors.title ? (
                    <Text mt={2} color="red" fontWeight="bold">{editProductFormik.errors.title}</Text>
                  ) : null}
                </Box>
```

The value for product.title now populates in the input field on the front end.

Comment: You can do it in same component too. You just need to add enableReinitialize: true as prop. Then initialValues can be updated

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai DUDE YOU FIXED IT THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!
Even after I submitted my answer, I was still struggling with seeing the initialValues updated because I saw it happen once and then never again and couldn't understand why. Thank you!! You saved me so much time. Have a great day sir.